# Function overloading with C++20 concepts but different cv-qualifiers: call is ambiguous

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

using namespace std;

void foo(const auto&)
{
    cout << "const auto&" << endl;
}

void foo(integral auto)
{
    cout << "integral" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo(5.5);
    foo(5);

    return 0;
}
```

In the case of `foo(5.5)`, the argument is not `integral` so there is no ambuigity
and `const auto&` is printed.

In the case of `foo(5)`, everything *would* also be fine **if** generic `foo` was defined with just `auto`.
But with `const auto&`, both functions are defined with different cv-qualifiers and it might be uncertain which one should be viable for the overload resolution.

GCC 12.2.0 fails with `call of overloaded ‘foo(int)’ is ambiguous`

However, Clang 14.0.6 works "as desired" and the resulting program prints `integral`.

What does the standard say here? I suppose it is not an undefined situation, so one of the compilers is probably not compliant with the standard...